# Find a orthogonal projection function $\cos t$ on kernel space $V = \operatorname{Span} \{\sin t, 1-\cos t\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In space $\operatorname{Span} \{1, \cos t, \sin t\}$ we have scalar product $$\langle\ f,g\rangle = \int_0^\pi f(t)g(t)dt$$

Find a orthogonal projection function $\cos t$ on kernel space $V = \operatorname{Span} \{\sin t, 1-\cos t\}$.

Do not know how to even start. Any help?

Comment: How would you do this if the vectors were elements of $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For a map $f \in V = \text{Lin}\{1, \sin t, \cos t\}$, the projection on $W= \{\sin t, 1-\cos t \}$ is a map $p(f)$ such that $p(f)(t)a \sin t+b (1-\cos t)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ must be defined by the fact that
$$\begin{cases}
\langle f-p(f), \sin t\rangle &=0\\
\langle f-p(f), 1-\cos t\rangle &=0
\end{cases}$$

That gives two equations for the two unknowns $a,b$.

*Note: if you know orthonormal basis and Gram–Schmidt process, there is a more generic process*

Comment: So if I understood you, my $f = 1$ or $f = sint$ or $f = cost$ and my $p(f) = asint + b(1-cost)$?

Comment: @NikiSedlarević Yes. Taking care that the $a,b$ are different for $1, \sin t, \cos t$.